# How to print record values without repeating certain fields in dataweave in CSV format based on specific conditions

Tags: csv, mule-studio, dataweave

Please consider the following input sample in CSV

```
Company,FirstName,LastName,Email
Rate,Manule,Reaya,Reaya@egetmetus.org
Rate,sholy,Bonvgy,Bonvage@mollis.org
```

The output should be as follows :

```
Company,FirstName,LastName,Email
Rate,Manule,Reaya,Reaya@egetmetus.org
,sholy,Bonvgy,Bonvage@mollis.org
```

The condition would be : if the company name repeats for different records in the input, it should be null in output CSV.

Please let me know if this can be handled in Dataweave component in Mule

Below is updated code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<mule xmlns:file="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/file" xmlns:dw="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/dw" xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core" xmlns:doc="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/documentation"
    xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-current.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/current/mule.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/file http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/file/current/mule-file.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/dw http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/dw/current/dw.xsd">

    <configuration doc:name="Configuration">
     <expression-language>
         <global-functions>
            def getCompanyName(Company){
                 if (flowVars.companyList contains Company) {
                    return "";
                 }  else {
                    flowVars.companyList.add(Company);
                    return Company;
                 }
            }
          </global-functions>
     </expression-language>
 </configuration>
    <file:connector name="File" autoDelete="true" streaming="true" validateConnections="true" doc:name="File"/>
    <file:connector name="File1" autoDelete="true" outputAppend="true" streaming="true" validateConnections="true" doc:name="File"/>
    <flow name="csvtocsvrecordemptyFlow">
        <file:inbound-endpoint path="src\test\resources\input" connector-ref="File" responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="File"/>
        <set-variable variableName="companyList" value="[[]]" doc:name="Variable"/>
        <dw:transform-message doc:name="Transform Message">
            <dw:set-payload><![CDATA[%dw 1.0
%output application/csv header=true
---
payload map {
    CompanyName: getCompanyName($.Company),
    name:$.FirstName
}]]></dw:set-payload>
        </dw:transform-message>

        <file:outbound-endpoint path="src\test\resources\output" outputPattern="test.csv" connector-ref="File1" responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="File"/>
    </flow>
</mule>
```

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, problem would be to store the used company names within memory by using just DataWeave. I don't think it can be done. But if you combine, MEL Global functions and DataWeave, you should be able to achieve this.

Add a global MEL function in mule config like below -

```
<configuration doc:name="Configuration">
     <expression-language>
         <global-functions>
            def getCompanyName(name){
                 if (flowVars.companyList contains name) {
                    return "";
                 }  else {
                    flowVars.companyList.add(name);
                    return name;
                 }
            }
          </global-functions>
     </expression-language>
 </configuration>
```

In your flow, initialize an empty array before dataweave.

```
<set-variable value="#[[]]" variableName="companyList" doc:name="Variable" />
```

Then, in dataweave, use the MEL function -

```
...
companyName: getCompanyName($.name)
...
```

You can write any custom logic in MEL function that can evaluate the name and return some value to DataWeave.

Comment: Hi Manik Thanks for the reply, but i am getting blank file. check my below code. check my below code

Comment: Have corrected the global function in else part and also the variable init to make it list. Please check now.

Comment: Still blank file is created,I have doubt here does the function call is happening?? when i debug the control is not even go there.I have updated the code above. Kindly check and let me know if am wrong somewhere.

Comment: Hi @Akilkarthik, please change the variable declaration value from `value=[[]]` to `value=#[[]]` (I missed it while copying). I am able to generate the output as you require by this code. The function we defined is a Global MEL function which is available to you anywhere inside your application. Think of it like `#[xpath3(...)]` inbuilt functions but this one is defined by you.

Comment: Global Functions doc - https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.7/dataweave-reference-documentation#global-mel-functions. You may not be able to debug that function as MEL.

Answer (score 0):

@Akil Karthik : When I am trying the solution it is still showing the coerce binary to array error. I have already provided the MIME type as application/csv in the variable declaration.