# CSV to CSV transformation using dataweave in mule

Tags: mule, dataweave

I have to do 1st level normalization from the input data coming from excel.[Input Excel][1].

Now the output shall be like[Output file][2]. I have tried using MEL(defining a method as global configuration) in combination of Dataweave. Inside dataweave I am trying to call the method defined above as global config. This approach is not working as the file generated is blank. Could anyone suggest a better approach or problem in this approach.
Below is the code 
@Manik:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<mule xmlns:dw="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/dw"
    xmlns:file="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/file" xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core" xmlns:doc="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/documentation"
    xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/dw http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/dw/current/dw.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-current.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/current/mule.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/file http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/file/current/mule-file.xsd">

  <configuration doc:name="Configuration">
     <expression-language>
         <global-functions>
            def getCompanyName(name){
                 if (flowVars.companyList contains name) {
                    return "";
                 }  else {
                    flowVars.companyList.add(name);
                    return name;
                 }
            }
          </global-functions>
     </expression-language>
 </configuration>


  <file:connector name="File" autoDelete="true" streaming="true" validateConnections="true" doc:name="File" readFromDirectory="C:\Users\Desktop\Mule-Doc"/>
    <file:connector name="File1" autoDelete="true" outputAppend="true" streaming="true" validateConnections="true" doc:name="File"/>


    <flow name="csvnormalizationFlow">
         <file:inbound-endpoint path="C:\Users\Desktop\Mule-Doc" connector-ref="File" responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="File"/>
        <set-variable value="#[[]]" variableName="companyList" doc:name="Variable" mimeType="application/csv"/>
        <logger message="The payload is-----------------------#[payload]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
        <dw:transform-message doc:name="Transform Message">
            <dw:set-payload><![CDATA[%dw 1.0

%output application/csv header=true
---
payload map {
    CompanyName: getCompanyName($.Company),
    location:$.Location
}]]></dw:set-payload>
        </dw:transform-message>

        <file:outbound-endpoint path="C:\Users\Desktop\Output" outputPattern="test.csv" connector-ref="File1" responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="File"/>
    </flow>
</mule>
```

Comment: Could you please post your MEL function and dataweave script

Comment: The MEL function is        <configuration doc:name="Configuration">
     <expression-language>
         <global-functions>
            def getCompanyName(name){
                 if (flowVars.companyList contains name) {
                    return "";
                 }  else {
                    flowVars.companyList.add(name);
                    return name;
                 }
            }
          </global-functions>
     </expression-language>
 </configuration>

Comment: The dataweave code is          <dw:transform-message doc:name="Transform Message">
            <dw:set-payload><![CDATA[%dw 1.0

%output application/csv header=true
---
payload map {
    CompanyName: getCompanyName($.Company),
    location:$.Location
}]]></dw:set-payload>
        </dw:transform-message>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Complete answer is here -https://stackoverflow.com/a/37123291/5616671

Can you post your flow xml here? I ran that code and it is giving me expected output.

Comment: I have added the code for your review. I am working on Community edition.

Comment: Is your logger printing payload before dataweave? Also please remove mime-type from set-variable declaration.

Comment: I changed `<file:inbound-endpoint path="C:\Users\Desktop\Mule-Doc"` to `<file:inbound-endpoint path="input"`. Also changed output path to just `output` folder in workspace. Then for an input csv with data `Company,FirstName,LastName,Email,Location
Rate,Manule,Reaya,Reaya@egetmetus.org,Test1
Rate,sholy,Bonvgy,Bonvage@mollis.org,Test2
` I above code worked for me to generate output csv like - `CompanyName,location
Rate,Test1
,Test2
`. Are you reading CSV or .XLS?

Comment: When i run the program it says "can not coerce binary to array" and the test.csvCSV has no data.

Comment: What is your input file? EXCEL or CSV? You will get that error if your input is excel (.xls/.xlsx) which will be read as input streams with binary data.

Comment: Thanks..it was Excel and I was in problem. This works good if I have to work on single level filtering (Company in this case). Now I am doing next level filtering here based on Location. I defined another method similar to getCompanyList() but it check on the previous value and in 3rd row of output it again gives the Bangalore as referred in input file. Please throw some light on this behaviour

Comment: For Location, you can change the function definition to accept current row instead of name and then call function as `functionName($)` in dataweave. Inside the function, you can apply your custom logic by evaluating all the attribute values. eg. Check Company name as well as location name combination before returning value. Please accept the answer if original question is resolved, that helps forum to stay clean :)

Comment: To add I have created another array variable to handle Location list before weave component.

Answer (score -1):

You can add a null handler un your Data weave expressions and the check if it is the payload that doesn't write anything. An example of null handle below.

```
 (payload.listAllFlightsResponse.*return default [])
```